# DIV block creation in magento 2.1 using xml layout

Tags: magento2, xml

I am trying to integrate custom template in magento2.1 as well as div container into footer block.

I am using below code in my layout but not working.

```
<container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" >
    <container name="footerContainer" htmlTag="div" htmlId="cart-container-id" htmlClass="cart-container" before="-">
    </container>
</container>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code.

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_company_links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links" after="footer_company_links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>    

        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="html/copyright.phtml"/>

    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

To add extra template

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Module\Vendor\Block\Myblock" name="custom-layout" template="test.phtml" ifconfig=""/>
</referenceContainer>
```